# Geospatial Queries in mongo db is not working with $maxdistance

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I am using geospatial indexing in mongodb to find and list the objects in db that are near a particular location. Here I use `$near` and `$maxDistance` to find the objects within a particular kilometer range. I am confused here in giving the value for `$maxDistance`. Can anyone help me understand what value(either km, m, or rad) do I want to give for `$maxDistance`?
Here is my db structure:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("556719a7e0550ca9d16ca303"),
        "Name" : "Apl",
        "loc" : [
                11.485489,
                77.247103
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("556719b1e0550ca9d16ca304"),
        "Name" : "Ind",
        "loc" : [
                11.462442,
                77.252167
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("556719bfe0550ca9d16ca305"),
        "Name" : " Ara ",
        "loc" : [
                11.452179,
                77.276629
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("556719eae0550ca9d16ca306"),
        "Name" : " Akodi ",
        "loc" : [
                11.455739,
                77.299278
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("556719f6e0550ca9d16ca307"),
        "Name" : " Kasi ",
        "loc" : [
                11.459693,
                77.328804
        ]
}
```

Here I used the following query to list the objects that are 5 kms from a particular location.

```
db.place.find({loc:{$near:[11.503993, 11.503993],$maxDistance:1000}});
```

The above query returns the following:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("556719a7e0550ca9d16ca303"), "Name" : "Apl", "loc" :
[ 11.485489, 77.247103 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("556719b1e0550ca9d16ca304"), "Name" : "Ind", "loc" :
[ 11.462442, 77.252167 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("556719bfe0550ca9d16ca305"), "Name" : " Ara ", "loc"
: [ 11.452179, 77.276629 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("556719eae0550ca9d16ca306"), "Name" : " Akodi ", "loc
" : [ 11.455739, 77.299278 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("556719f6e0550ca9d16ca307"), "Name" : " Kasi ", "loc"
 : [ 11.459693, 77.328804 ] }
```

But If I use the query with `$maxDistance:66` it returns nothing. What value should I be using for `$maxDistance` to get the objects with in 2 kms?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like min and max distance are measured in meters:

```
{
  $near: {
     $geometry: {
        type: "Point" ,
        coordinates: [ <longitude> , <latitude> ]
     },
     $maxDistance: <distance in meters>,
     $minDistance: <distance in meters>
  }
}
```

radians are used with legacy coordinates.

source:  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/

Comment: but if I give the value say $maxDistance:2000(2kms) it returns all the objects

Comment: I'm not real up to date on geography.  However it looks like the 5 values you have provided are all quite close to each other.  Do you know how far away from each other your values are? Are you certain that they are more than 2000m apart? @HarshaVardhan

Comment: Yes they are close to each other by 2 to 3 kilometers. The coordinates for '$near' is away from all other coordinates in db by more than a kilometer

Comment: but if `$near` is more than 1000 meters and less than 2000 meters, then the behavior is correct.  You should test with a `$near` value of 1000 and 1500 and see if it starts to retrieve different values.  @HarshaVardhan

Comment: If I use the query like this db.place.find({loc:{$near:[11.503993, 11.503993],$maxDistance:65.7450}}) it returns only the first object and if I change the value of maxDistance to 65.7490 it returns the first two objects. May I know why this happens and any one please clear me what values should I be using for $maxDistance?

Comment: It sounds like it's working properly.  It's hard to say because all your locations are so close to each other.  Are you able to add some more locations, whose distance from your `$near` you know?  Ideally you would add a location that is 500, 1000, 1500, 2000 meters away, and then put those values in your `$maxDistance`.  @HarshaVardhan

Comment: `$near` is going to return all the locations that are in your `$maxDistance`.  So if all locations are within your `$maxDistance` range, you will get all locations.

Comment: The objects in db are like this. objB(db coordinate) is 2 kilometers away from objA($near coordinate), objC(db  coordinate) is 2 kilometers away from objB, 4 kilometers away from objA and objD(db coordinate) is 2 kilometers away from objC, 4 kilometers away from objB and 6 kilometers away from objA

Comment: @HarshaVardhan I'm playing around with google maps, is your example above (near 11.503993, 11.503993) the locations you are using?

Comment: $near coordinates are 11.503909, 77.243756

Comment: @HarshaVardhan your test coordinates are good for testing.  I don't know why you are getting those results.

Comment: I used the radian value for $maxDistance say for $nearSphere - 6/6371 and for $near - 6(10/6371) and it worked fine for me. Here I have converted the km value in to radian value. I did not know the fact here that why I am using 6(10/6371) for $near instead of 6/6371. So basically if we want to convert a kilometer value into radian value the formula used is km/6317.